Overfilled my m.2 nvme drive
Hi there I was doing data recovery with photorec and unfortunately I filled the SSD to its maximum now my operating system won't boot
I've tried recovery mode with the making space option but it wasn't enough
is there anything I can do to salvage my data?

Which version of Windows or Linux are you using?

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ellyfish

@PontifexMaximus I wrote your 'solution' as an answer, next time you can just answer your own question.  Editing the 'question' to say "Solved" isn't actually how to mark things solved here on Ask Ubuntu, writing an answer and accepting it is.

Use a LiveUSB of Ubuntu while your M.2 is present, unlock the device by mounting it with the Disks application, and then clear up space on your filesystem.  That should solve the problem.
Additionally, consider getting external storage to store data you don't absolutely need to keep on your system.


Most of this answer is based on the edit by OP, but by this now being an answer (and Community Wiki since I don't want the credit for the points) it can be accepted.

